# Key bindings don't work when using askopenfilename dialog in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, key-bindings

I'm working on a simple app for reading and displaying sequences of image files from within a zip file using python 3.4 with tkinter, like you might use for reading .cbz comic book files. Ideally I'd like to bind the left and right keys to show the last and next images respectively. This works fine if I specify the name of the zip file in the code; however, if I use filedialog.askopenfilename() dialogue box to specify the file, then the keyboard key bindings no longer work.

I assumed this was due to a focus issue, and I've tried setting the focus to the label to which the keys are bound (both using the label.focus_set() method and the parent option of the askopenfilename() dialogue) without success.

Code is below. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, as it's starting to drive me nuts.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import io
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import zipfile

class ComicDisplay():
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
        self.parent = master
        self.fname = ""
        self.label = Label(frame, bg="brown", height=500)
        self.current_zip_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[(zip, "*.zip")])
        # self.current_zip_file = "C:\\Users\\Alexis\\Dropbox\\Photos.zip"
        self.image_list = self.acquire_image_list(self.current_zip_file)
        self.current_image_number = 0
        self.pil_image = self.acquire_image(self.current_zip_file, self.image_list[self.current_image_number])
        self.tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.pil_image)
        self.parent.title(self.fname)

        self.label.configure(image=self.tk_image)
        self.label.focus_set()
        self.label.bind("<Configure>", self.image_resizing)
        self.label.bind("<Left>", self.get_last_image)
        self.label.bind("<Right>", self.get_next_image)
        self.label.bind("<Button-1>", self.get_next_image)
        self.label.pack(padx=5, pady=5, fill='both', expand=1)

    def acquire_image_list(self, zip_file):
        image_list = []
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, "r") as myFile:
            for filename in myFile.namelist():
                image_list.append(filename)
        image_list.sort()
        return image_list

    def acquire_image(self, zip_file, image_file):
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, "r") as myFile:
            self.fname = image_file
            image_bytes = myFile.read(image_file)
            data_stream = io.BytesIO(image_bytes)
            pil_image = Image.open(data_stream)
            pil_image = self.image_sizer(pil_image)
            return pil_image

    def image_sizer(self, image_file, window_size=500):
        w, h = image_file.size
        if w > h:
            image_file_height = int(h*(window_size/w))
            image_file = image_file.resize((window_size, image_file_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        else:
            image_file_width = int(w*(window_size/h))
            image_file = image_file.resize((image_file_width, window_size), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        return image_file

    def image_resizing(self, event):
        new_height = root.winfo_height() - 14
        new_size_image = self.image_sizer(self.pil_image, new_height)
        self.tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(new_size_image)
        self.label.configure(image=self.tk_image)

    def get_next_image(self, event):
        if self.current_image_number >= len(self.image_list)-1:
            self.current_image_number = 0
        else:
            self.current_image_number += 1
        self.update_image()

    def get_last_image(self, event):
        if self.current_image_number == 0:
            self.current_image_number = len(self.image_list)-1
        else:
            self.current_image_number -= 1
        self.update_image()

    def update_image(self):
        self.fname = self.image_list[self.current_image_number]
        self.pil_image = self.acquire_image(self.current_zip_file, self.image_list[self.current_image_number])
        self.tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.pil_image)
        self.parent.title(self.fname)
        self.image_resizing(None)




root = Tk()
app = ComicDisplay(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You declare image_list as an empty list every time  acquire_image_list is called so there is only the current file name in the list.  A simple print statement will tell if that is the problem or not.  Pass image_list to the function as well as returning it from the function or use an instance object --> self.image_list.

Comment: I vaguely recall reading a bug report a few years ago specifically related to opening a dialog on windows before the main window comes up. You might try waiting until after the UI is initialized before using the file dialog.

Comment: @CurlyJoe - acquire_image_list should only be called once, after the zip file is chosen. It should be emptied every time, so that the list only contains the images from one file.

Comment: @BryanOakley - I'll give this a try and see if it helps. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2):

Bryan's comment held the answer: delaying the open file dialogue until after the window was initialized solved the problem. Instead of opening the file when the app starts, creating a file open method allows the key bindings to work as they should.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `root.update()` before and after `askopenfilename()`, the key bindings work.